# How to make an event trigger multiple components in Angular2

Tags: events, service, angular, components

I have an input component, an output component, and a processing service. I would like the user to input a string, and for the processing service to output a processed message to the output component. The trouble I am having is getting the processed message from the processing service. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
<input class="input" type ="text"[(ngModel)]="text" (keyup.enter)="process(text)">
export class InputComponent {
    text: String;
    constructor(private processService: ProcessService){}
process(text){
        this.processService.process(text);
}
}
export class ProcessService {
processedMsg: string;
    process(msg) {
    this.processedMsg = "a message thats processed";
    }
    getMessage() {
    return this.processedMsg;
    }
    }
        export class OutputComponent {
    output: string;
            constructor(private processService: ProcessService){}
            getOutput() {
                this.output = this.processService.getMessage();
            }
```

How can I make it so that when the user presses enter, the input is processed, and is given to the output? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to achieve the effect your going for.  This first way is the simplest to grasp I think and it follows what you have so far pretty closely.  All this does is directly tell the template to display the value that the service last processed, *this is not recommended*.

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
class ProcessService {
  processedMsg: string = "";
  process(msg) {
    this.processedMsg = "Processed: \""+msg+"\"";
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'output',
  template: '<span>{{processService.processedMsg}}</span>'
})
class OutputComponent {
  constructor(public processService: ProcessService){}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [OutputComponent],
  providers: [ProcessService],
  template: `
    <input class="input" type ="text" [(ngModel)]="text" (keyup.enter)="process(text)"><br>
    <output></output>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  text:string;
  constructor(private processService: ProcessService){}
  process(text){
    this.processService.process(text);
  }
}
```

We could also do this using Observables, see this answer for the source: [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924#35568924)

```
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Injectable()
class ProcessService {
  private _processedMsgSrc: BehaviourSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  processedMsg = this._processedMsgSrc.asObservable();
  process(msg) {
    this._processedMsgSrc.next("Processed: \""+msg+"\"");
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'output',
  template: '<span>{{output}}</span>'
})
class OutputComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  output:string;
  private _subscription:Subscription;
  constructor(public processService: ProcessService){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.processService.processedMsg.subscribe(
      msg => this.output = msg
    );
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // stop the subscription when the component is destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [OutputComponent],
  providers: [ProcessService],
  template: `
    <input class="input" type ="text" [(ngModel)]="text" (keyup.enter)="process(text)">
    <br>
    <output></output>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  text:string;
  constructor(private processService: ProcessService){}
  process(text){
    this.processService.process(text);
  }
}
```

The second way would probably be better as it completely separates the two components, allowing you to change how the Process Service works completely without changing any other code.